# Fn keys on hid keyboard always lock in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

How do I unlock `fn` keys? It is always "locked" whenever I used my keyboard.

So it is difficult to use this keyboard as I have to press the `Fn` key all the time when I type something on my keyboard.

My question is how to make my keyboard act normally and so that I do not have to hold the `Fn` key all the time?

Comment: Whar did you mean by `type`? What key do you want to unlock? `F1`..`F12`?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/233579-how-do-u-turn-off-fn-lock-on-laptops/) details some of the potential problems:

If you are getting weird text like

```
he3* th5s s4c2s - th5s 5s w5th64t h63d5ng the f 2ey
```

when you type

```
help this sucks - this is without holding the f key
```

Then it may be that rather than your Fn key being locked you instead have you <kbd>Numlock</kbd> enabled and a "short" keyboard that lacks a number pad and instead uses an `Fn` key to toggle `Numlock`.  Try pressing either the <kbd>Numlock</kbd> key or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Numlock</kbd> to toggle `Numlock` status.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue with a **Cherry MX-Board 1.0** keyboard. Rebooting didn't help, and neither did unplugging / re-plugging the keyboard.

It turns out the solution to get out of the `Fn lock` mode on this particular keyboard is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd>

So it seems the key combination depends on which keyboard you're using.

The user manual of the keyboard actually mentions this behavior, so try to find the manual for your model.

Answer (score 0):

I use a tiny generic BlueTooth MiniKeyboard, and had this exact same symptom. No version of the "toggle NumLock, stupid!" solution worked for me. In desperation, I found online an old USRobotics manual for this keyboard and learned that

Fn + <-Enter->

toggles FN-lock on and off.

Your mileage may vary, of course; and I have no idea if other keyboards use this convention. But many  bluetooth mini-keyboards seem to come from the same factory -- so if NumLock doesn't work for you, try this.

[Grrrr. Several hours of life wasted. I never imagined that in 2015 I would have to RTFM to use a KEYBOARD.

I wonder how much money the factory saved by NOT printing on the  key a little orange "Fn Lock" (after all, the Fn key itself is orange, and all the other g**d*mn keys on this thing have the result of pressing Fn together with that key printed on the key). I'm sure it's not as much as I will have to pay a lawyer to help me, should I ever find the product manager of this keyboard -- because after wasting so much time on such a stupid issue, I will certainly murder him/her should I ever knowingly make his/her acquaintance.]
Apologies for the rant.